# Vue Composition API TypeScript ref typing not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to use the Vue composition API with TypeScript to get a little more familiar with the upcoming changes and I'm running into a small but annoying error.  When I try to instantiate a typed value using "ref" in the script below I'm getting an error of "number is not defined".  From what I can see in the Typing section of https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#ref, though, I'm doing it correctly.  If I remove any attempt to type the "ref", though, it works as it implicitly types it as a number.  This is my first foray into using TypeScript so I may be wrong, but since I know x will be a number I thought I should be explicitly declaring the type and not relying on implicit typing.  I'm posting my code snippet below.  I don't have a deployed copy because this is literally the first thing I'm trying to do and I didn't think to try to deploy it for this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>{{ x }}</p>
    <p>{{ y }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { createComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api';

  export default createComponent({
    setup() {
      const x = ref<number>(0);
      const y = ref(0);
      return {
        x,
        y,
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Working fine with me, on what typescript version are you?

Comment: You should use https://typescript.nuxtjs.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just throwing this out there to close the question but after doing a full restart of the project it seems to work.  There must have been something I copied over incorrectly from the setup docs.